# asp.net core A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, routes

I have an ASP.Net Core 2 Web application.

I'm trying to create a custom routing Middleware, so I can get the routes from a database.

In `ConfigureServices()` I have:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => 
    options.UseMySQL(configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionClient")));
services.AddScoped<IServiceConfig, ServiceConfig>();
```

In `Configure()`:

```cs
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.Routes.Add(new RouteCustom(routes.DefaultHandler);
    routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

In the `RouteCustom`

```cs
public class RouteCustom : IRouteCustom
{
    private readonly IRouter _innerRouter;
    private IServiceConfig _serviceConfig;

    public RouteCustom(IRouter innerRouter)
    {
        _innerRouter = innerRouter ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(innerRouter));
    }

    public async Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
    {
        _serviceConfig = context.HttpContext
            .RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceConfig>();
        /// ...
        // Operations inside _serviceConfig to get the route
    }

    public VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(VirtualPathContext context)
    {
        _serviceConfig = context.HttpContext
            .RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceConfig>();
        // ...
        // Operations inside _serviceConfig to get the route
    }
}
```

The `IServiceConfig` it is just a class where I access the database to get data, in this case the routes, but also other configuration data I need for the application.

```cs
public interface IServiceConfig
{
    Config GetConfig();
    List<RouteWeb> SelRoutesWeb();
}

public class ServiceConfig : IServiceConfig
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IServiceTenant _serviceTenant;

    public ServiceConfig(IMemoryCache memoryCache,
                        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
                        IServiceTenant serviceTenant)
    {
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _serviceTenant = serviceTenant;
    }


    public Config GetConfig()
    {
        var cacheConfigTenant = Names.CacheConfig + _serviceTenant.GetId();

        var config = _memoryCache.Get<Config>(cacheConfigTenant);
        
        if (config != null) 
            return config;

        config = _unitOfWork.Config.Get();
        _memoryCache.Set(cacheConfigTenant, config,
            new MemoryCacheEntryOptions() 
            { 
                SlidingExpiration = Names.CacheExpiration 
            });

        return config;
    }


    public List<RouteWeb> SelRoutesWeb()
    {
        var cacheRoutesWebTenant = Names.CacheRoutesWeb + _serviceTenant.GetId();

        var routesWebList = _memoryCache.Get<List<RouteWeb>>(cacheRoutesWebTenant);
        
        if (routesWebList != null) 
            return routesWebList;

        routesWebList = _unitOfWork.PageWeb.SelRoutesWeb();
        _memoryCache.Set(cacheRoutesWebTenant, routesWebList, 
            new MemoryCacheEntryOptions() 
            { 
                SlidingExpiration = Names.CacheExpiration 
            });

        return routesWebList;
    }
    
}
```

The problem is I'm getting this message when I test with multiple tabs opened and try to refresh all at the same time:
"A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed"

I'm sure there is something I'm doing wrong, but I don't know what. It has to be a better way to access the db inside the custom route middleware or even a better way for doing this.

For example, on a regular Middleware (not the routing one) I can inject the dependencies to the Invoke function, but I can't inject dependencies here to the RouteAsync or the `GetVirtualPath()`.

What can be happening here?

Thanks in advance.

---

**UPDATE**
These are the exceptions I'm getting.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

And this one:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> MySqlException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

This is the UnitOfWork

```cs
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    ICompanyRepository Company { get; }
    IConfigRepository Config { get; }
    
    // ...

    void Complete();
}


public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

        Company = new CompanyRepository(_context);
        Config = new ConfigRepository(_context);
        // ...
    }

    public ICompanyRepository Company { get; private set; }
    public IConfigRepository Config { get; private set; }
    
    // ...

    public void Complete()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 2**

After reviewing the comments and making a lot of tests, the best clue I have is when I remove the CustomRoute line the problem disappear. Removing this line from Configure function on Startup.cs

```
routes.Routes.Add(new RouteCustom(routes.DefaultHandler));
```

Also I have tried removing, first the RouteAsync and then the `GetVirtualPath()` methods, but if one of those is present I get an error, so it is clear that the problem is in this `CustomRoute` class.

In the `TenantMiddleware`, which is called first for any request, I'm injecting the UnitOfWork and I have no problem. This Middleware is create in the Configure function:

```
app.UseMiddleware<TenantMiddleware>();
```

And inside, I'm injecting the UnitOfWork, and using it on every request, like this:

```cs
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IServiceTenant serviceTenant)
{
    // ...performing DB operations to retrieve the tenent's data.
}

public class ServiceTenant : IServiceTenant
{
    public ServiceTenant(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, 
                        IMemoryCache memoryCache,
                        IUnitOfWorkMaster unitOfWorkMaster)
    {
            _unitOfWorkMaster = unitOfWorkMaster;
    }

    // ...performing DB operations
}
```

SO, the problem with the `CustomRoute` is I can't inject the dependencies by adding to the Invoke function like this:

```cs
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IServiceTenant serviceTenant)
```

So I have to call the corresponding Service (Inside that service I inject the UnitOfWork and perform the DB operations) like this, and I think this can be the thing that is causing problems:

```cs
public async Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
{
    _serviceConfig = context.HttpContext
        .RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceConfig>();
    // ....
}
```

because this is the only way I know to "inject" the `IServiceConfig` into the RouteAsync and `GetVirtualPath()`...

Also, I'm doing that in every controller since I'm using a BaseCOntroller, so I decide which os the injection services I use...

```cs
public class BaseWebController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IUnitOfWorkMaster _unitOfWorkMaster;
    private readonly IServiceConfig _serviceConfig;
    private readonly IServiceFiles _serviceFiles;
    private readonly IServiceFilesData _serviceFilesData;
    private readonly IServiceTenant _serviceTenant;

    public BaseWebController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _memoryCache = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMemoryCache>();
        _unitOfWork = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUnitOfWork>();
        _unitOfWorkMaster = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUnitOfWorkMaster>();
        _serviceConfig = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceConfig>();
        _serviceFiles = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceFiles>();
        _serviceFilesData = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceFilesData>();
        _serviceTenant = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceTenant>();        
    }
}
```

And then in every controller, instead of referencing all of the injected services, I can do it only for those I need, like this:

```cs
public class HomeController : BaseWebController
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public HomeController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : base(serviceProvider)
    {
        _unitOfWork = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUnitOfWork>();
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I don't know if this has something to do with my problem, but I'm just showing you what I think can be the problem, so you can have more information.

Thanks.

**UPDATE 3**

This is the code of the db to retrieve the routes:

```
public class PageWebRepository : Repository<PageWeb>, IPageWebRepository
{
    public PageWebRepository(DbContext context) : base(context) { }


    public List<RouteWeb> SelRoutesWeb()
    {
        return Context.PagesWebTrs
            .Include(p => p.PageWeb)
            .Where(p => p.PageWeb.Active)
            .Select(p => new RouteWeb
            {
                PageWebId = p.PageWebId,
                LanguageCode = p.LanguageCode,
                Route = p.Route,
                Regex = p.PageWeb.Regex.Replace("<route>", p.Route),
                Params = p.PageWeb.Params,
                Area = p.PageWeb.Area,
                Controller = p.PageWeb.Controller,
                Action = p.PageWeb.Action,
                Type = p.PageWeb.Type,
                Sidebar = p.PageWeb.Sidebar,
                BannerIsScript = p.PageWeb.BannerIsScript,
                Title = p.Title,
                Description = p.Description,
                Keywords = p.Keywords,
                ScriptHead = p.ScriptHead,
                ScriptBody = p.ScriptBody,
                BannerScript = p.BannerScript,
                BannerUrl = p.BannerUrl,
            })
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Where PagesWebTrs are the translations of the pages (multi language) and PagesWeb is the main table.

Comment: Please post a full stack trace of the exception and _all_ its inner exceptions

Comment: Thanks Steven, I have updated my question with the full stack trace

Comment: Can you show the IUnitOgWork implementation?

Comment: I have updated my question with the IUnitOfWork

Comment: It seems like the same instance of DbContext is accessed at the same time in 2 different places or threads somehow

Comment: You're either doing something wrong or it's a bug :D

Comment: Yes, but how is it possible when I'm creating the IUnitOfWork with the AddScope? That means that every request is creating a new one, right? COuld it be in the same request? But this only happends when I user multiple windows to test several requests at the same time...

Comment: Still not enough info I think, because you didn't show the code of UnitOfWork (not interface but implementation), and that is where exception is thrown.

Comment: I have updated my question with the implementation of the UnitOfWork...let me know if you need anything else. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the question with more info and my thinking about where can the problem be. It's clear it is something inside the CustomRoute...

Comment: Are you using `await` on all async calls against the `DbContext`?

Comment: I have no async calls against the database, all of them are "normal" sync calls. The only async call I have is the RouteAsync, but I'm not calling that function...it is an internal function.

Comment: Well, I see nobody has a clue on this...is there any other way to do a routing from database? I'm using the RouteAsync & GetVirtualPath to check on the database for the routes. I have a CRM where the admin of each site can change the name of the URLs for each page on the public site, and also it is multilinguage, so I need to check the routes on the database...if there is another way...

Comment: No one can help you if you're not going to show the relevant code. Eg. what code does `_unitOfWork.PageWeb.SelRoutesWeb();` do? The exception is EF related, so don't hide the db operations under `...performing DB operations` comments. Would be great if you could provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code.

Comment: You are absolutely right @gldraphael, that wasn't my intention though. Please, if you want to help me, ask me to show the code you think it is relevant. I have no problem sharing code at all, but I imagined the db code you are refering to was trivial. I have edited my question with the code of that repository. Thanks.

Comment: Please try this: In RouteCustom Replace `_serviceConfig = context.HttpContext ...` with `var serviceConfig = context.HttpContext ...` and use that variable instead of the instance field `_serviceConfig`. Do this in both methods. If it works, I'll explain ... not vary practical in a comment.

Comment: It looks like it is working. Thanks. But, I'd like to know why is working this way...do the middleware share all the instance variables with all the requests??? I has to be something like that...

Comment: I'll in explain in an answer; so that this question is valuable to others having a similar issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This issue is indeed within the route middleware.

Per definition, a middleware is a singleton, so a single instance handles all requests. This results into the instance state (`the IServiceConfig`with hooked up `DbContext`) being accessed and changed by multiple simultaneous requests; it's a well disguished classical concurrency issue.

An example.

Request A executes `RouteAsync`, sets the `_serviceConfig` and executes a query on the `DbContext`. Nano seconds (or less :)) later, request B does the same. While request B's query is being executed, request A executes `GetVirtualPath`, but this time on the `DbContext` set by request B. This results in a second query being executed on the `DbContext` of request B which still has one running and you get the mentionned error.

The solution is to prevent shared state, by retrieving the `IServiceConfig` at the start of each method.

*As you already said, getting such a dependency injected via the `Invoke` method does not work; the `Invoke`method does not get executed.*

Here below is the reworked `RouteCustom`.

```
public class RouteCustom : IRouteCustom
{
    private readonly IRouter _innerRouter;

    public RouteCustom(IRouter innerRouter)
    {
        _innerRouter = innerRouter ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(innerRouter));
    }

    public async Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
    {
        var serviceConfig = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceConfig>();
        // ...

    }

    public VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(VirtualPathContext context)
    {
        var serviceConfig = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceConfig>();
        // ...

    }
}
```

Comment: the solution you gave me not only works (I have to do more tests) but also you have given me an explanation why. I didn't know the middleware worked like this. Thanks a lot.